# TypeScript and JSON with list of objects in object?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have a question. Why Typescript with Angular dont map list of objects in object properly?

In my scenerion, i have Company that includes Employees and Products. TypeScript's model looks like this:

```
import { Product } from "./product";
import { Employee } from "./employee"; //my own classes

export class Company {
  id: number; //my own class
  name: string;

  products: Product[] = []; //company have products and employees
  employees: Employee[] = [];
}
```

My WebApi, that is `ASP .NET WebApi2` returns me JSON that looks like this:

```html
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "userId": "98560542-0202-48b6-b8c5-cde945151527",
      "joinDate": "2015-07-20T00:00:00",
      "companyId": 29
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 29,
      "name": "xxx",
      "companyId": 29
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "zzz",
      "companyId": 29
    }
  ],
  "id": 29,
  "name": "companyName8",
}
```

Form that response above i get `employees` and `products` without a type. Items in there are only objects. To avoid that, i added this lines to my `subscribe()` method (where i getting `company`):

```
    company: Company = new Company();
    comanyProducts: Products[] = [];

    for (const item of this.company.products) {
          this.companyProducts.push(Object.assign(new Product(), item));
          //this.companyProducts its a new list to store 
          //company's products with proper type of Product
        }
```

its not a big deal when i have 10 or 100 products but what to do when we have 10000 or 100000 items on list? Why i cant just use this (from it, i just get list of `Object`, not list of `Product` that i want to):

```
this.companyProducts = this.company.products
//it is in my subscribe
```

What i do wrong and how to fix that?

**EDIT**

My API FUnc that cant handle list of objects in object:

```
public getObject<T>(
    type: new () => T,
    id: number
  ): Observable<DataResponse<T>> {
    const url = `${this.getUrl(type)}${id}`;
    return this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(
      map((input: Object, indx: number) => {
        const inputObject: T = input as T;
        const outputObject = new type();
        Object.assign(outputObject, inputObject);
        return new DataResponse(outputObject);
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<T>(`get${type.name} id=${id}`))
    );
  }

//i call it like this: this.dataService.getObject(Company).subscribe(resulut => { this.list = result.object});
```

Then in subscribe i just do `Object.assign` in foor loop

Comment: please include you service call in angular.  HttpClient in Angular should be able to handle this scenario

Comment: edit, i used this.getUrl to get current endpoint url